# How would I go about styling echo?

Tags: php, css

I was wondering how would i go about styling a echo in php? im trying to style the paragraph tag nested inside one of the echos, i'd be grateful if anyone can tell me how to do this. thanks

PHP

```
if(isset($_SESSION['sess_user_id']) && $_SESSION['sess_user_name'] != "") {
echo '<h1>Welcome '.$_SESSION['sess_user_name'].'</h1>';
echo "<p id="profileText"This is your personal profile page, from here you can edit events</p>";
echo '<h4><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></h4>';
} 
else { 
header('location:index.php');
```

CSS

```
#profileText {
top: 40%;
position: absolute;
color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, don't do presentation from within your php logic.  Consider this:

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_user_id']) || $_SESSION['sess_user_name'] == "") {
    header('location:index.php');
}

// do any other php stuff...

?>
<h1>Welcome <?= $_SESSION['sess_user_name'] ?></h1>
<p id="profileText">This is your personal profile page, from here you can edit events</p>
<h4><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></h4>
```

This way,

- Your logic and presentation are clearly separated
- If you want to change the presentation, you don't have to mess around with your php code
- You don't have to worry about single quote / double quote / escape quote / blah, blah, blah.
- You don't have to worry about output before the header
- The programmer that comes after you will be amazed at how clean your code is :)
- It lets you easily see typos: `<p id="profileText"This is your personal profile page, from here you can edit events</p>`

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error.

```
echo "<p id="profileText"This is your personal profile page, from here you can edit events</p>";
```

Use single quote in your echo.

```
echo "<p id='profileText'>This is your personal profile page, from here you can edit events</p>";
```

If you are use double quote in your echo, you can't use another double quote in your string. You can do on this way:

```
echo "<p id=\"profileText\"> This is your personal profile page, from here you can edit events</p>";
```

Or you can use single quote on your string

```
echo "<p id='profileText'>This is your personal profile page, from here you can edit events</p>";
```